# How to know the feature count of a specific class in text classification?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, text-classification, naivebayes

I'm trying to calculate the prediction probabilities for a certain text. There're problems with the classification of those texts. The text should be classified as class B but it's assigned class A. So I want to calculate the probability manually. But I need the feature count for Class A and B. All what I have is the total feature count which is 60343.

So how can I get the feature count for each class?

I'm doing dialect text classificaiton. and using scikit learn.

Comment: What is your definition for `feature count for each class`? Because each feature could be present in all classes!

Comment: @ai_learning I mean the features that have one occurrence or more in one class